# node.js - Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "users": syntax error

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to put a JSON object "Synced" (Which you will see in the code)
This is the code for a function "addServer(userid, serverid)"
The function is being required from another javascript file

```
     db.all(`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Tag = ? LIMIT 1`, userid, async(error,element) => {

       if(element[0].Synced === '') {
         var sJSON = {
           users:{
             [userid]:4,
           },
           servers:[`${serverid}`]
         }

        var serverJSON = JSON.stringify(sJSON)
         console.log(serverJSON)
} else { 
  //Else statement not done yet
}
 db.run(`UPDATE Users SET Synced = "${serverJSON}" WHERE Tag = "${userid}"`)
})
```

Solved. Needed to change quoting.

Comment: Did you check the quoting? You're switching between interpolation, which won't escape automatically, and substitution, which should.

Comment: In general you should add an answer rather than embedding the answer in the question, and be specific, especially since it seems like my comment pointed you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave Newton said, I had to check my quoting. What I did was change my double quotes to single quotes which solved the problem.